# Why many times file names would be of the pattern - x86_64-pc-linux-gnu

Tags: linux

I have seen files names in Linux environment to be of the pattern -

```
x86_64-pc-linux-gnu

x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc

i386-pc-linux-gnu
```

Looks like the first part of the name - `x86_64` or `i386`indicates the hardware architecture.

But would like to know how the entire name is formed? How the other parts of the name is formed?

Comment: Please add a bit of context to the question. There are naming conventions on Linux, but they vary from one scenario to the next. Where have you seen these file names?

Comment: Couple of them are as seen from this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/64355722/5347487. And another one whole googling - https://linux.die.net/man/1/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc. And one more instance where I've seen this is the name of the executable of our application which runs on Linux.

Answer (score 4):

These are “configuration names”, also known as “triplets”. The best description I know of is in [Ian Lance Taylor’s documentation for the GNU configure and build system](https://www.airs.com/ian/configure/configure_4.html).

Configuration names are split into up to four components (up from three initially, hence the “triplet” moniker):

- the CPU or architecture (`i386`, `x86_64`, `arm`...)
- the “manufacturer” (`pc` in your examples)
- the kernel (`linux`)
- the operating system, which often boils down to the C library (`gnu`, *i.e.* the GNU operating system, including the GNU C library) but can be more specific (`gnueabihf` on ARM, *i.e.* the GNU operating system, using the ARM “Embedded” ABI and hardfloat)

Some of these can be omitted, for example `pc` in your second example; [`config.sub`](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=config.git;a=blob_plain;f=config.sub) will give you the canonical form for any “triplet” it recognises:

```
$ /usr/share/misc/config.sub x86_64-linux
x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
$ /usr/share/misc/config.sub djgpp
i586-pc-msdosdjgpp
$ /usr/share/misc/config.sub mingw32
i686-pc-mingw32
$ /usr/share/misc/config.sub vaxv
vax-dec-sysv
```

There are also variants for targets with no kernel and/or operating system, for example `arm-none-eabi`, `x86_64-pc-elf`, or even `x86_64-pc-none`.

These configuration names are used to describe build targets, and are commonly seen when cross-compiling (but not only). They can be used as arguments to a number of `configure` options, and as prefixes for build tools; thus `x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc` is GCC building for `x86_64-linux-gnu`.

Their construction is somewhat arcane and can lead to [lengthy debates](https://bugs.debian.org/606825)...